# Error when try to deploy in windows phone

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework

I am developing an app with Ionic framework and I need the application in windows phone. When I try to deploy the application with Visual Studio 2015 I get this error the following error:

> Installation of the application failed. There are pending operations
>   in the deployment queue windows phone

I'm searching for solutions but look like if no one have this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed Windows SDK?

Comment: Yes, I have. And I follow all the recommendations for configure correctly the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never find an answer to solve this problem so I start a new cordova project from Visual Studio and then I migrate all the application to this new project. This works really fine and now the app is running correctly in windows phone. I highly recommend do this, because the project created from Visual Studio is now the base to the other platforms.